# How is it that Apache and Firefox can use port 80 (or sometimes port 8080) simultaneously?

Tags: apache, firefox, port

The Apache webserver uses port 80 to listen for incoming requests and replies over port 80. Firefox uses port 80 to send requests to webservers and then listens on port 80 for the response from the webserver. I have run Apache and Firefox simultaneously before and am just wondering how two different programs can share the same port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each side of a TCP network connection is defined by a touple of (ipaddress, port #).  When a packet leaves your system all it knows is that it needs to find ip address 192.168.1.1 and go the whoever has a socket bound to port 80.
A server socket is going to be defined by the address on which Apache is listening and port 80.  The client socket open by Firefox will have the same ip address but a different randomly assign port number which you normally do not see.
You can see it using netstat or tcpview (Windows)
For example when I run netstat right now I see:

```
tcp4       0      0  x.x.x.x.62993    stackoverflow.co.https ESTABLISHED
```

where x.x.x.x is my laptops ip address and 62993 is the random port number assigned to my web browser.

Answer (score 1):

Firefox isn't listening to port 80. It's making a request to a server port and handling the response.